# How to have different type of variable in report(.rdlc)

Tags: rdlc

I have a table in `MS-access` like this:

[image]

the format of this column is ShortText

when I want to use it in a report designer I want to convert it's number to have only 2 decimal number and I do that using following expression:

```
=IIF(isNumeric(Fields!Val.Value),FormatNumber(Fields!Val.Value,2),(Fields!Val.Value))
```

this code do what I want in number variable but instead of getting `> 305`
I get `#Error`

[image]

where is the problem?

Comment: @Reniuz Hi, Can you help me on this? I'm kinda stuck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Access, all of the expressions in an IIf() must be able to be evaluated even if not the one returning the result. FormatNumber() errors on the string '>305' and causes the IIf() to return error. The real issue here is bad design. Numeric data should be in a number type field.

How many variations of comparison operators or other non-number characters are used? Are there <=, >=, < comparison operators? Your code will have to extract the prefix characters if they are present. Consistency in structure is essential when manipulating strings. If the prefix is always only '>':

=IIf(IsNumeric([Val]), FormatNumber(Replace([Val],">",""), 2), [Val])

Otherwise, might require a custom function in VBA.

NOTE: Val is a reserved word in Access (it is a function) - should avoid reserved words as names for anything.

Comment: Tanks a lot,
Tanks for your explanation, I will consider them,
the prefix is either > or <

Comment: If only the two possible prefixes, can use nested Replace(): =IIf(IsNumeric([Val]), FormatNumber(Replace(Replace([Val],">",""),"<",""), 2), [Val])